# Custom TControl doesn't paint at design time until cut and pasted

Tags: delphi, controls, custom-controls, delphi-xe2

I have an odd issue with TChromeTabs. I know it must be something simple, but I can't figure out what needs to be done to fix it.

When I initially drop the TChromeTabs control on a form it is completely transparent. If I cut the control then paste it back to the form the contents are displayed correctly. The contents also appear if I close, then re-open the form.

As I have no idea why this is happening I can't really give you any code samples. However, you can download the source code here: http://code.google.com/p/delphi-chrome-tabs/downloads/list.

Comment: This is *your* control, right? It hasn't always behaved this way, has it? If not, then you introduced some change that caused this problem. Check the revision history to find where you introduced the bug. You can use `svn-bisect` to help narrow your search.

Comment: @Rob - Yes, it's a control I wrote. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether or not it has always behaved like this. Once the initial controls were on the demo form, they stayed there. Of course, I can go back through all the revisions and see if one of them removes the odd behaviour, but I was hoping somebody might be able to give me a clue as to what might be causing it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your control doesn't paint itself because you disable painting. [You call `BeginUpdate` in the constructor](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-chrome-tabs/source/browse/trunk/Lib/ChromeTabs.pas?r=33#1348), and [you don't call `EndUpdate` until the `Loaded` method](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-chrome-tabs/source/browse/trunk/Lib/ChromeTabs.pas?r=33#3125) is called. But `Loaded` is only called when *loading* a control from a persisted state. Usually, we think of that as being when the control is loaded from a DFM file, but the IDE uses the same technique to allow putting controls on the clipboard.

You haven't noticed this before because, apparently, you only test your control by opening a pre-made demo project. The demo project has a control in its DFM file, so the only code path you exercise is the DFM case. You don't exercise the path where the constructor is called directly — when the control is first dropped on a form, or when the control is created "dynamically" in code.

To fix this, begin by getting rid of [the `BeginUpdate` call in your constructor](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-chrome-tabs/source/browse/trunk/Lib/ChromeTabs.pas?r=33#1348). Instead, to check whether your control is still in the process of being constructed, check `csCreating in ControlState`.

You can also get rid of your `stsLoading` state. Delphi already gives you that with the `csLoading` bit of `ComponentState`. Besides, your use of `stsLoading` is wrong since [you set it in the constructor](https://code.google.com/p/delphi-chrome-tabs/source/browse/trunk/Lib/ChromeTabs.pas?r=33#1338), just like you do with `BeginUpdate`.

Instead of relying on `Loaded` being called, you might wish to move certain code into the `AfterConstruction` method. Put code there that needs to run after your component is created but that has nothing to do with loading properties from a DFM (or other persistence source). I'm not sure I see *anything* in your `Loaded` method that really belongs there. Nearly all of it should be able to occur in the constructor.

You should also be aware of the `CreateWnd` method. It's called when your control's window handle gets allocated. That's where you should start allowing paint operations to occur. When you don't have a window handle, you have nothing to paint to.

Comment: Many, many thanks. I truly appreciate you putting in the time to help me out. I think the main issue was that I misunderstood when Loaded was called. Please feel free to review my code whenever you like :)